# Nunit - how can I grab data from the nunit compiler?

Tags: nunit, specflow, specrun, test-reporting

I know that there is a way for me to pull data out of the NUnit compiler but cannot find the web URLs with the documentation. Essentially it was how to setup a class with getter setters to pull NUnit time run, assert results, name, literally anything I want.

Not sure even if this route would be viable anymore because I am not using SpecRun with NUnit.

My Goal:

- Trying to have a scenario run,
- before it would log when it starts, the name of the scenario and what feature it is in.
- Once finished it would also grab finish time and the result of test case

Once it hits teardown, it would store all this information into a JSON object that I can send off to a DB somewhere to play with however I please.

Comment: Are you using NUnit 2 or 3? In NUnit 3, you can create an engine extension to wrap a test run, that might get you started.

Comment: SpecRun and NUnit3

Answer (score 1):

You can use TestContext/ScenarioContext/FeatureInfo/ScenarioInfo classes to pull information about features and tests at run time. You can capture the start and finish times yourself in the setup and tear down methods.

Comment: I was able to get up to the ScenarioContext and it is apparently utilizing Dictionaries: KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
When I peek into it, looks like the kvp is String, Object

Comment: So when I get to ScenarioContext, looks like there is using Dictionary<string, object>
realizing what I think you mean, inside the BeforeScenario, AfterFeature, etc. I would create like a public List<string> Use Stopwatch for the time and have it EndOfTestRun take the list and place it in a JSON object and serialize it?